# When back pressed go to main Activity from fragment (Navigation view)

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, back, navigationview

Tried many ways, but none works perfectly. I want to get main activity from the fragments set up in a navigation view. 
I tried

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
}
```

but it won't function properly. I want it like when I'm in a fragmented activity it returns back to main and while clicking back again it quits (I already did this), help me out with  when back pressed get back to main activity

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 1000 ;

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

private AdView mAdView;

ImageView imageView;


RecyclerView recyclerView;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

List<Item> items;
CustomAdapter adapter;
private long backpressedtime;




@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    switch (requestCode)
    {
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
        {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
                Toast.makeText(this, "Permission Granted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(this,"Permission Denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            break;

        }
    }




private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String str="Click on Wallpaper to set  Wallpaper";
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    mDrawerLayout=(DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.dl);
    mToggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,mDrawerLayout,R.string.open,R.string.close);
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
    mToggle.syncState();
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.Navigation_v);
    setupDrawerContent(navigationView);
    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

    recyclerView =(RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);




    initItem();






    //start service and play music
    startService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SoundService.class));






}
public void toast(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wallpaper Set", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
private void  initItem() {

    items = new ArrayList<>();

    items.add(new Item(0,"Wide","https://images8.alphacoders.com/532/thumb-1920-532407.jpg"));
    items.add(new Item(1, "Wide","https://images5.alphacoders.com/394/thumb-1920-394511.jpg"));
    items.add(new Item(1,"Wide","https://images5.alphacoders.com/408/thumb-1920-408539.jpg"));


    adapter = new CustomAdapter(this,items);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);





}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

protected void onDestroy() {
    //stop service and stop music
    stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SoundService.class));
    super.onDestroy();
}
public void selectItemDrawer(MenuItem menuItem){
    Fragment myFragment = null;
    Class fragmentClass;
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {

        case  R.id.walkthrough:
            fragmentClass = Walkthrough.class;
            break;

        case R.id.info:
            fragmentClass = About.class;
            break;
        default:
            fragmentClass = Walkthrough.class;


    }
    try {
        myFragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flcontent,myFragment).commit();
    setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();







}
private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            selectItemDrawer(item);
            return true;
        }
    });
}




@Override
public void onBackPressed() {


    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?");
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setNegativeButton("No Stay ;-)", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            dialogInterface.cancel();
        }
    });
    builder.setPositiveButton("Yes :'-(", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();

}
```

Walkthrough.java

```
public class Walkthrough extends Fragment {


// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public Walkthrough() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment Walkthrough.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static Walkthrough newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    Walkthrough fragment = new Walkthrough();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment


    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_walkthrough, container, false);

    WebView webView = (WebView)v.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); //enable javascript
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());    //important to open url in your app
    webView.loadUrl("http://ign.com/wikis/the-last-of-us/Prologue");
    return v;



}

// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

}

Comment: add backstack whenever you are adding the fragment

Comment: Can you add your fragmented activity's backpress code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to go back to the **MainActivity** onBack click of **WalkthroughFragment** then while commit your fragment add it to **BackStack** using this method:

```
FragmentTransaction addToBackStack (String name)
```

This method will do the below operation:

Will Add this transaction to the back stack. This means that the transaction will be remembered after it is committed, and will reverse its operation when later popped off the stack.

You can use it like that

```
FragmentTransaction ftx = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ftx.replace(R.id.my_container_frame, fragment);
ftx.addToBackStack(null);
ftx.commit();
```

Comment: can you ellobrate more, like where to add

Comment: @AnishJain You can use it in your **selectItemDrawer(MenuItem menuItem)** method where you are trying to commit the fragment

Answer (score 0):

**Alternatively you include all the function invocations on a single line**

```
 getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace('Your Fragment Container ID', new 'Fragment Class Name').addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

Cheers!